# error in Android Studio: Method (onClick) does not overrride method from its superclass

Tags: android, android-fragments, overriding

In an Android Studio Java class that implements a fragment logic (SavvyFragment.java) I have a method onClick that handles the different buttons of the view.
It was copied and adapted from an activity class that is working.
However, it does not compile because it states the error in the title: Method does not overrride method from its superclass.
Also intriguing, for me, is the hint that this onClick(View v) has no usages.

This is the method declaration head ...

```
    /* Button listener callback */
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //region start button clicked
            if (v.getId() == com.example.devcapture.R.id.gadget_start_button) {
                String address = this.macAddressTV.getText().toString();
                String pin = this.pinTV.getText().toString();
...
```

Error is on the @Override annotation line.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,
David Mendes

I tried to compile and were expecting no errors

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I have to go back to basics and read the errors properly.

If there is no method in the superclass to override, why do I have to annotate with @Override.

I commented it, and everything is working now.

Hello ..... McFly .....

Thank you everybody.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).